# Print array in the table td

Tags: javascript

I am new in Javascript, I have an array, and want to print it in the table `td`.

This is my array:

```
array = [100, 200, 300];
```

This is my table:

```
<table>
  <th> Result</th>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td> My result 1</td>
     <td class='result'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> My result 2</td>
     <td class='result'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> My result 3</td>
     <td class='result'></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to print my array in the `td` with class name `'result'`

Comment: A loop maybe? Hints: `let results = document.querySelectorAll(".result")` ...`results[i].textContent = array[i]`

Comment: please share code what you you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```js
const array = [100, 200, 300];

const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.result')];

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  elements[i].textContent = array[i];
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th> Result</th>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td> My result 1</td>
     <td class='result'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> My result 2</td>
     <td class='result'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> My result 3</td>
     <td class='result'></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the array and use the current index for the HTML element as well.

Possible ES5-only solution:

```js
var array = [100, 200, 300];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("result")[i].innerHTML = array[i];
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th> Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td> My result 1</td>
       <td class='result'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td> My result 2</td>
       <td class='result'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td> My result 3</td>
       <td class='result'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: You need an equal amount of array elements and elements with the `.result` class.

Comment: Both of the answers I see above need a bit more work, to check/avoid going past the end of both arrays...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("result")


var array = [100,200,300]

for (var i=0;i<result.length;i++){

  result[i].innerHTML = array[i];
}
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/fifojufayu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id attribute to the table tag, id = "tab". Then add the below javascript code

```
pointer=0
arr=[100,200,300];
// selecting all the tags having result as class name 
var nodes=document.getElementById("tab").getElementsByClassName("result");
arr.forEach((ele)=>{nodes[pointer].innerHTML=ele;pointer+=1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

- I use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- It considers the case if the array elements and the quantity of rows are diffrerent.
- Also added '.myTable' to prevent target other '.result' nodes out of the selected table.

Hope it helps.

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <th> Result</th>
<tbody>
  <tr><td> My result 1</td><td class='result'></td></tr>
  <tr><td> My result 2</td><td class='result'></td></tr>
  <tr><td> My result 3</td><td class='result'></td></tr>
  <tr><td> My result 4</td><td class='result'></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
    const array = [100, 200, 300];
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.myTable .result')  // <-- I added '.myTable' to prevent target other '.result' nodes out of the selected table
    
    rows.forEach((row, i) => {
      if (array[i]) row.innerHTML = array[i]  // <-- I replace the innerHTML if the array has content at that index
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you... No need to update table according to array data....

Table code:

```
<table>
    <th colspan="2" >Result</th>
    <tbody id="myTableBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script>
  var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTableBody');

  var array = [100, 200, 300];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      tableChild = document.createElement('tr');
      tableChild.innerHTML = "<td> My result "+(i+1)+"</td><td class='result'>"+array[i]+"</td>";
      tableRef.appendChild(tableChild);
  }
</script>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/Nishanth_V/pen/rEZmxN

Answer (score -1):

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('result');

var array = [100, 200, 300];

for(var i =0 ; i < el.length && i < array.length; ++i) {

    el[i].innerHTML = array[i];

}
```

Comment: Hi Ranjith! Thank you for posting an answer to this question. In this community that you are now part of, we like to give complete answers. Please, edit your answer and add context around your code, so your fellow users will have a better idea what it is it accomplishes.

Answer (score -1):

You have to replace `'` by `"` and add numbers to your class , after that your code with look like this:-

```
<table>
  <th> Result</th>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td> My result 1</td>
     <td class="result1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> My result 2</td>
     <td class="result2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> My result 3</td>
     <td class="result3"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Your JavaScript code will look like this:-

```
<script>
var array = [100, 200, 300];
array.foreach(function (item, index){
  var resultNum = index + 1;
  document.getElementByClassName("result" + resultNum).innerHTML = item;
});
</script>
```